# Can I compare the forecasting performance of two models VECM and VAR

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, vector-error-correction-model

Can I compare the forecasting performance of two models VECM and VAR with the same dataset, if in the case of VECM I have some of the variables I(1) at the level, and others are stationary?

Comment: If you are forecasting the same target variable, then of course you can compute errors for both forecasts and compare them. What is your question?

Comment: @StephanKolassa, If I use one dataset, will they contradict each other in terms of interpretation? If I take in VECM part of the variables at the level, and other part stationary, and in VAR everything is in the form I (0).